# Swagger can't generate schema when using DTO in controller method as param

Tags: .net-core, swagger, dto

I have an API controller `MemberController`:

[image: MemberController]

I have a `Member` model class in the `Models` folder of my project:

```
public class Member
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Mobile { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    public MemberType MemberType { get; set; } = MemberType.Player;
    public MemberStatus MemberStatus { get; set; } = MemberStatus.Created;
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

I also have a view model / Dto class in the `ApiModel` folder of my project:

```
namespace bengalfc.API.ApiModel
{
    public class CreateMember
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use Entity Framework in my project to update database structure with migrations.

The `Member` model is the reflection of my `Member` table in the database. Initially while using the `Member` model as the parameter for the `CreateMember` method, I got an error saying certain fields are required, I didn't want to solve this error by using data annotations, instead, I chose to create a DTO or view model named `CreateMember` in the `ApiModel` folder.

Until now my Swagger was loading the API documentation perfectly, but as soon as I started to use the `CreateMember` model in the `CreateMember` method; Swagger complained

> SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate schema for type - bengalfc.API.Models.CreateMember.

How would I use a view model or DTO in the controller action in this case, or what would be the ideal solution for this scenario?

Comment: use `[FromBody]` try once

Comment: for more info follow the answer given

Answer (score 1):

Use `[FromBody]` before property class datatype as shown in the below code it help you Betar `swagger` documentation.

```
   [HttpPost("members")]
    [Produces("Application/json")]
    public ActionResult CreateMember([FromServices] IMemberservice memberService, [FromBody] CreateMember InP)
    {
        var Result = memberService.CreateBusinessActionforprocess(InP);
        return Ok(Result);
    }
```

as shown in above no need of creating constructor and inject interface  from `.Net Core 5` you can use `[FromServices]`.
you are using Route parameter in PUT method you can use `[FromRoute]` as below

```
public ActionResult CreateMember([FromRoute] int memberId, [FromBody] Member InP)
```